# Остановить всплытие для css hover

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Есть такого рода легкий кодик для модалки:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease 0s;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease 0s;
}

.modal-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.modal-overlay .window {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-overlay">
  <div class="window"></div>
</div>
```

Основная цель в том, чтобы при ховере фона, он должен изменяться в `opacity`, а при ховере на целевом элементе с классом `.window`, `opacity` у фона должен возвращаться на исходную.
Что-то похожее с событиями в js, но только в css. Как можно решить это?

Comment: Так пропишите hover для window. В примере hover только для фона прописан.

Comment: @labris нужно при ховере `.window` не применять стили, которые указаны при ховере `.modal-overlay`.  Мне не нужно писать в ховере для `.window` `opacity:1`. Не в этом состоит вопрос.

Comment: @labris, смысл в том, что ховер на `.modal-overlay` распространяется на все вложенные элементы вглубь по ДОМ. Как этого избежать, чтобы ховер действовал конкретно на `.modal-overlay` и ни на что другое?

Comment: Посмотрите тут. Если не поможет, тогда через js без проблем.
https://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/

Comment: @labris я это находил. Там в примере одна вложенность, что исключает вариант с чистым css в моем примере (вроде бы). А через js-то понятно, что без проблем.

Comment: Тогда через CSS в вашем примере никак не сделать. Это все потому, что Cascading только сверху вниз работает, и тут уж ничего не поделать.

Comment: @labris ужастно ): Придется через js.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя прозрачность будет наследоваться на дочерние элементы. Создай див-обертку и в нем спозиционируй фон и окно, так они не будут зависеть друг от друга

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="window"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не неси чушь, `opacity` не наследуется. [Пруф](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Summary). И вопрос не в свойстве как таковом, вопрос о всплытии.

Comment: @Geyan, у тебя проблемы с доверием сайту Мозилы? Окей, чувак, посмотри на допотопном [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/css/opacity). И финальная "точка": если бы свойство `opacity` наследовалось, то достаточно было бы прописать `.window:hover {opacity:1}`, чтобы при ховере на модалке непрозрачность была равна единице. Вот пруф на codepen - vk.cc/6m44OT. Но увы! Такого не происходит, из чего делается подтверждение факта. Не несите тут чушь, пожалуйста. И вопрос, я повторяю, не в этом, а конкретно в `hover`, которое работает на вложенных элементах при наведении на родительский.

Comment: я лишь проверяю по факту, к поримеру не применяя rgba сделайте прозрачный фон т.е background только с opacity и увидите как "не наследуется opacity" к примеру вот :http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/LWyQRV?editors=110 для div.a установлен фон red с opacity .5 а для div.b blue opacity 1 , ну какого чёрта он всё равно прозрачен на 50% ??

Comment: @VostokSisters я спутал терминологию, прошу прощения.
Если задать opacity блоку, в котором находится дочерний, то непрозрачность применится ко всему блоку в целом, то есть и дочерний станет прозрачным. Успокойся.

Comment: @ИсмаилМагомедов скажи это лучше Geyan, который не согласен со всеми стандартами мира и авторитетными сайтами по css.