# HTML CSS hover на основной элемент но не дочерний

Tags: html, css

Допустим есть html страница и в ней body. Как сделать в CSS чтобы свойство применялось при наведении на общий документ но только если курсор не в области дочернего body?

Что-то на подобии:

```
html:not(body:hover):hover {
    //
}
```

Comment: уффф... Сложновато объяснено... Можно ли объяснить поподробнее для чего нужно это "наведение"?

Comment: Весёлый вопрос :-D

Comment: @Antonio112009 подозреваю, что для подобного - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637979/265406

Comment: @UModeL оуу... понятненько